# checkbox enable onload to display other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Ok, The question here is to allow a form to grab information from a mysql settings, like enabled or disabled. then a checkbox is going to determine if the the 3 following text fields (box123) are going to be enabled or disabled depending on that request.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" id="checker" checked=checked>Enabled?
        <br>
        <input type='text' name="details" id="tb1" value='box1'>
        <br>
        <input type='text' name="details" id="tb2" value='box2'>
        <br>
        <input type='text' name="details" id="tb3" value='box3'>
        <br>
    </form>
</body>

</html
```

>

test.js Jquery code which allows the check to be enabled or disabled depending on the activation varible

```
toggleInputs($('#checker'));

$('#checker').click(function () {
    toggleInputs($(this));
});

function toggleInputs(element) {
    if (element.prop('checked')) {
        $('#tb1').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#tb2').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#tb3').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#tb1').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#tb2').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#tb3').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go... Actually using jquery as your question asked:

**HTML**

```html
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" id="checker" checked=checked>Enabled?
    <br>
    <input type='text' name="details" id="tb1" value='box1'>
    <br>
    <input type='text' name="details" id="tb2" value='box2'>
    <br>
    <input type='text' name="details" id="tb3" value='box3'>
    <br>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   toggleInputs($('#checker'));
   $('#checker').click(function () {
       toggleInputs($(this));
    });
});

function toggleInputs(element) {
    if (element.prop('checked')) {
        $('#tb1').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#tb2').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#tb3').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#tb1').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#tb2').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#tb3').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9Lg4/40/

When the initial call is made the elements in the body are not yet loaded. You can wrap the first call to toggleInputs in a JQuery ready event function or place the script tag that includes test.js after the form.

Comment: i'm not sure why, but when i test this out on my host it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using JQuery or just JavaScript?

Comment: yea, the new code does not allow me to place the script above the form, it still needs to be below

Comment: Why not just `$('#tb1,#tb2,#tb3').prop('disabled', element.prop('checked'));`? (Within the function, obviously.)

Comment: @David Your solution is very clean and concise.

http://jsfiddle.net/MVGys/9/

This is your solution and it works as he suggested with a couple minor adjustments. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555181/jquery-multiple-check-box-enable-text-field

Answer (score 3):

While you've already accepted an answer, I feel that answer over-complicated the solution somewhat, and left in unnecessary redundancy. That said, I'd suggest the following approach:

```
function toggleInputs(element) {
    /* using a multiple selector
       checking whether the check-box is checked or not using ':is()`,
       which returns a Boolean */
    $('#tb1, #tb2, #tb3').prop('disabled', element.is(':checked'));
}

$('#checker').change(function(){
    // event-handling (reacting to the change event)
    toggleInputs($(this));
    /* the next change() (without arguments) triggers the change event,
       and, therefore, the event-handling */
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MVGys/).

Amended the above function (using the `!` operator) to have the fields editable while the `input` is `checked`, and `disabled` while the `input` is unchecked:

```
function toggleInputs(element) {
    $('#tb1, #tb2, #tb3').prop('disabled', !element.is(':checked'));
}

$('#checker').change(function(){
    toggleInputs($(this));
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MVGys/10).

References:

- [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: well the previous question (Before i edited it) was asking for the following: the check mark is going to be enabled or disabled depending on a mysql field. and the fields need to be enabled when checked, and disabled when unchecked. your example was given by someone else that also didn't read my question (before it was edited) i'm going to go ahead and stick with happy's solution. thanks anyway

Comment: for example if you removed checked=checked the check box is unchecked and the fields are open, rendering your script useless

Comment: i take it back, this script does NOT work, its the same problem with happy prior to his last edit. the script has to be below the form in order to work.

Comment: i have a new question
http://jsfiddle.net/Q9Lg4/46/
what if i want to use 2 input on the same form, i can't just duplicate the code? using happy's code please

Comment: If you have another question, ask another question. If you have questions regarding his answer, and how to extend it, then ask *him*. Basically, though, you need wrap the relevant check-boxes with the relevant inputs, and use context, rather than `id`s, to select the correct inputs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555181/jquery-multiple-check-box-enable-text-field