# jquery multiple check box enable text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

from previous questions [checkbox enable onload to display other elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554413/checkbox-enable-onload-to-display-other-elements)

ok, since none of these worked, im going to have to just display my actual code instead of an example. i was just trying to use an example then apply it to my problem, but none of your solutions worked with my situation.

so here it is. $stuff comes from mysql and is either enabled or disabled, the check mark needs to be checked if the $stuff is 'enabled' or unchecked if 'disabled'.

HTML

```
<tr>
  <td>blah</td>
     <td>
        <?php 
        if ($stuff1 == 'enabled'){
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='a1' id='checker' checked=checked>";
        } else {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='a1' id='checker'>";
        }
        ?>
      </td>
      <td></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
     <td><div align="right">a1:</div></td>
     <td><input id="tb1" type='text' name='a1_1' size='25' maxlength='5' value='<?php echo $a1_1 ?>'></td> 
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><div align="right">a2:</div></td>
      <td><input id="tb2" type='text' name='a2_2' size='25' maxlength='5' value='<?php echo $a2_2 ?>'></td> 
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><div align="right">a3:</div></td>
       <td><input id="tb3" type='text' name='a3_3' size='25' maxlength='5' value='<?php echo $a3_3 ?>'></td> 
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><div align="center">Activate Something Else</div></td>
       <td>
        <?php 
        if ($stuff2 == 'enabled'){
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='b1' id='checker2' checked=checked>";
        } else {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='b1' id='checker2'>";
        }
        ?>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div align="right">b1:</div></td>
        <td><input id="tb4" name="b1_1" type="text" size="25" maxlength='5' value='<?php echo $b1_1 ?>'></td>        
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><div align="right">b2:</div></td>
        <td><input id="tb5" name="b2_2" type="text" size="25" maxlength='5' value='<?php echo $b2_2 ?>'></td>        
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><div align="right">b3:</div></td>
        <td><input id="tb6" name="b3_3" type="text" size="25" maxlength='5' value='<?php echo $b3_3 ?>'></td>        
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
```

This is was my previous jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            toggleInputs($('#checker'));
            $('#checker').click(function () {
                 toggleInputs($(this));
            });
        });

    function toggleInputs(element) {
        if (element.prop('checked')) {
            $('#tb1').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#tb2').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#tb3').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#tb1').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#tb2').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#tb3').prop('disabled', true);
        }
}
```

if tested you can see that the top check mark only functions with the 2nd input on the form.

My situation: in this form, you have 2 values $stuff1 and $stuff2, the options they have are either enabled or disabled, they will never be consistent. when php test's if the value is enabled, the value checks the check mark, and enables the 3 box fields. if it's disabled, the check mark is unchecked and the 3 boxes display is as grayed out. The user can now check (to enable) the checkmark and display the 3 text fields, or uncheck (to disable) the check mark and gray out the 3 fields.

this will eventually goto a POST at the bottom and send all the values of the fields and the check marks back to mysql.

I was able to do this flawless here http://jsfiddle.net/MVGys/9/ with only 1 checkmark, not multiple checkmarks on the same form.

Comment: What's the question>?

Comment: i already asked it: but now i want to be able to do this with 2 check boxs that are independent from each other but on the same FORM.

Comment: I'm a bit confused because your fiddle is already working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated Answer*

Given what you seem to be trying to accomplish I think using classes and data attributes might serve as the easiest and most flexible solution.

**OP's HTML (Modified)**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>blah</td>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='a1' class="group_ctrl" data-group="group_a" id='checker'>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div align="right">a1:</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="tb1" type='text' class="group_a" name='a1_1' size='25' maxlength='5' value='a1_1'>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div align="right">a2:</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="tb2" type='text' class="group_a" name='a2_2' size='25' maxlength='5' value='a2_2'>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div align="right">a3:</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="tb3" type='text' class="group_a" name='a3_3' size='25' maxlength='5' value='a3_3'>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div align="center">Activate Something Else</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='b1' class="group_ctrl" data-group="group_b" id='checker2' checked=checked>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div align="right">b1:</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="tb4" name="b1_1" class="group_b" type="text" size="25" maxlength='5' value='b1_1'>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div align="right">b2:</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="tb5" name="b2_2" class="group_b" type="text" size="25" maxlength='5' value='b2_2'>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div align="right">b3:</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="tb6" name="b3_3" class="group_b" type="text" size="25" maxlength='5' value='b3_3'>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.group_ctrl').change(function () {
        // gets data-group value and uses it in the outer selector
        // to select the inputs it controls and sets their disabled 
        // property to the negated value of it's checked property 
        $("." + $(this).data("group")).prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    }).change();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5rRj/8/)

I have given every input you want to disable/enable a class. E.g. group_[a|b]
Then I gave the check-box controls a class group_ctrl and a data attribute named group (data-group) with the corresponding group class it is responsible for controlling as the value. You can duplicate this pattern as many times as needed. E.g. group_c, group_d, group_e... etc.

Comment: no it doesn't work, because if you load the page without checked=checked, it's unchecked and the text fields are enabled. http://jsfiddle.net/Q9Lg4/63/

Comment: Indeed it does not. I updated my answer. However, you should consider accepting Tushar's answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer and given a working example. If this is not an adequate solution to the problem please explain what exactly is not working given your situation. Thanks and hope this helps!

Comment: works like magic, can you show me an example of allowing me to place the script in my head or above the form?

Comment: Sure the above JsFiddle is now executed in a JQuery ready handler.

Comment: happhuman: i'm using this script. http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/
and the way to applies the style to the checkbox or radio button is to use class='styled' to trigger the jquery/css code to style it. this seems to be conflicting with your script. i can only do 1 or the other, is there a quick fix to be able to apply the style and your code to work together?

Comment: i've attempted to combine the 2 class='styled group_ctrl' but it doesn't work

Comment: is it possible check the trigger from class to id for group_ctrl

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9Lg4/69/)

Use `nextUntil()` to find all text boxes until next check box and toggle them. You are using the IDs of elements, please note that you may also use the type of the element to select and work on them all.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // add click function and then call toggleInputs on every checkbox on the page
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
        toggleInputs($(this));

    }).each(function () {
        toggleInputs($(this));
    });
});

function toggleInputs(element) {
    // careful, it will find all elements until next checkbox
    element.nextUntil('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', !element.prop('checked'));
}
```

But seriously, you need to structure the HTML code properly. if you do, you can use `parent()`, `siblings()` etc functions much more effectively and meaningfully.

Comment: in my example the names on the 2 input check box's are different. you're works if the names are the same only. so this doesnt work.

Comment: @Sickest JS code works perfectly; it doesn't use name property at all.

Comment: @Sickest looks like you are trying to address other questions in this. please check how the values are returned to backend when there are multiple elements with same name property. That doesn't have anything to do with this question. :-)

Comment: yea, i'm not sure, when i tested it, it didnt work, it works regardless of the name change does work on jsfiddle, but it does not work with my actual code. i'm not trying to address any other questions, its the same situation, only problem is none of these work with my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest :)

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Q9Lg4/62/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
         $(this).nextUntil('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    }).change();
});
```

[.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do like this:

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" id="checker" >
<br>
<input type='text' name="details" id="tb1" value='box1'>
<br>
<input type='text' name="details" id="tb2" value='box2'>
<br>
<input type='text' name="details" id="tb3" value='box3'>
<br><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" id="checker2" >
<br>
<input type='text' name="details" id="tb4" value='box1'>
<br>
<input type='text' name="details" id="tb5" value='box2'>
<br>
<input type='text' name="details" id="tb6" value='box3'>
<br>
</form>
<script>
toggleInputs($('#checker'));

$('#checker').click(function () {
toggleInputs($(this));
});

function toggleInputs(element) {
if (element.prop('checked')) {
/* 
$('#tb1').prop('disabled', false);
$('#tb2').prop('disabled', false);
$('#tb3').prop('disabled', false);
*/
$(element).parent('form').find('input[type=text]').attr('disabled',false);
} else {
/*
$('#tb1').prop('disabled', true);
$('#tb2').prop('disabled', true);
$('#tb3').prop('disabled', true);
*/
$(element).parent('form').find('input[type=text]').attr('disabled',true);
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: this does not work, if you place checked=checked on the top input, both are enabled on page run, rendering your script useless i'm afraid